# Reusing of Variable and memory concept in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, extern

If I declare a variable as - extern int c; // I can reuse this variable in another function and no memory is allocated to it.

If I initialize a variable as - uint32 a[32]; // 32*4 bytes of memory is allocated.how to to reuse the above variable in another program ? Example : I am using a pointer to access the value or address of it.

Comment: MAIN.c : extern uint32 a[32]; and try to reuse it in a another program as i

Comment: What do you mean by "another program"? Do you mean like [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) between processes?

Comment: If you get compiler or linker errors, please edit your question to include them (complete and unedited). Also please edit your question to show a complete code example (also known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)). You should probably also read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it will help you write better questions in the future.

Comment: @user2984410 Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `extern`  only when you have multiple source files. An extern variable is a declaration of a variable which is defined in another translation unit. Compiler allocates storage when the variable is defined  
Refer to [THIS POST ON SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how) for more information

Comment: MAIN.h : extern int a;     ONE.c : int a[32];  TWO.c : int *p; p=&a;    // I will include MAIN.h in both ONE and TWO program. why isn't working ??

Comment: int a and int a[] are different. One is array. Change your extern to extern int a[32];

Comment: MAIN.h : extern int a[32]; ONE.c : int a[32]; TWO.c : int *p; p=&a; // why it's not working ?? I am including .h file in both program.

Comment: Compile using gcc ONE.c TWO.c -o main

Comment: I am using visio c++ as IDE.

Comment: Error c2061: identifier 'a' 
error C2059: syntax error :  syntax error ';' 
Error c3409: empty attribute block is not allowed

Comment: I solved it : I forgot to put typedef unsigned _int32 uint32 ;